# How do I write a simple regular expression pattern matching function in C or C++?

Tags: c++, c, regex, algorithm

This is a question in my paper test today, the function signature is

```
int is_match(char* pattern,char* string)
```

The pattern is limited to only ASCII chars and the quantification `*` and `?`, so it is relatively simple. `is_match` should return 1 if matched, otherwise 0.

How do I do this?

Comment: Are there parentheses in your regex or are the * and ? only applied to single characters?

Comment: @A.Rex,no parentheses.the * and ? is the same meaning as defined by regex

Comment: @Tracy: There are a lot of different interpretations and implementations of regular expression matchers, and they don't all work identically.  It is important that you understand which interpretations was meant, in order to answer this question correctly.

Comment: Very interesting question! =) I thought it was simple for a second but then there are so many possibilities and combinations right? (I mean you can use combinations of * and ? as many times you like in the pattern correct?)

Comment: @Tracy: This wasn't nearly as easy as I first thought it would be :)  I wish you luck

Comment: @Merlyn,yes,i just thought it is hard for me to do it,well,at least at that moment.

Answer (score 14):

[Brian Kernighan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brian_Kernighan) provided a short article on [A Regular Expression Matcher](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/spr09/cos333/beautiful.html) that [Rob Pike](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rob_Pike) wrote as a demonstration program for a book they were working on. The article is a very nice read explaining a bit about the code and regular expressions in general.

I have played with this code, making a few changes to experiment with some extensions such as to also return where in the string the pattern matches so that the substring matching the pattern can be copied from the original text.

From the article:

> I suggested to Rob that we needed to find the smallest regular
>   expression package that would illustrate the basic ideas while still
>   recognizing a useful and non-trivial class of patterns. Ideally, the
>   code would fit on a single page.
>
> Rob disappeared into his office, and at least as I remember it now,
>   appeared again in no more than an hour or two with the 30 lines of C
>   code that subsequently appeared in Chapter 9 of TPOP. That code
>   implements a regular expression matcher that handles these constructs:
>
> ```
> c    matches any literal character c
> .    matches any single character
> ^    matches the beginning of the input string
> $    matches the end of the input string
> *    matches zero or more occurrences of the previous character
> ```
>
> This is quite a useful class; in my own experience of using regular
>   expressions on a day-to-day basis, it easily accounts for 95 percent
>   of all instances. In many situations, solving the right problem is a
>   big step on the road to a beautiful program. Rob deserves great credit
>   for choosing so wisely, from among a wide set of options, a very small
>   yet important, well-defined and extensible set of features.
>
> Rob's implementation itself is a superb example of beautiful code:
>   compact, elegant, efficient, and useful. It's one of the best examples
>   of recursion that I have ever seen, and it shows the power of C
>   pointers. Although at the time we were most interested in conveying
>   the important role of a good notation in making a program easier to
>   use and perhaps easier to write as well, the regular expression code
>   has also been an excellent way to illustrate algorithms, data
>   structures, testing, performance enhancement, and other important
>   topics.

The actual C source code from the article is very very nice.

```
/* match: search for regexp anywhere in text */
int match(char *regexp, char *text)
{
    if (regexp[0] == '^')
        return matchhere(regexp+1, text);
    do {    /* must look even if string is empty */
        if (matchhere(regexp, text))
            return 1;
    } while (*text++ != '\0');
    return 0;
}

/* matchhere: search for regexp at beginning of text */
int matchhere(char *regexp, char *text)
{
    if (regexp[0] == '\0')
        return 1;
    if (regexp[1] == '*')
        return matchstar(regexp[0], regexp+2, text);
    if (regexp[0] == '$' && regexp[1] == '\0')
        return *text == '\0';
    if (*text!='\0' && (regexp[0]=='.' || regexp[0]==*text))
        return matchhere(regexp+1, text+1);
    return 0;
}

/* matchstar: search for c*regexp at beginning of text */
int matchstar(int c, char *regexp, char *text)
{
    do {    /* a * matches zero or more instances */
        if (matchhere(regexp, text))
            return 1;
    } while (*text != '\0' && (*text++ == c || c == '.'));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

See [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3523323/code-golf-regex-parser) for a solution you can not submit.  See [this paper](http://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html) for a description of how to implement a more readable one.

Comment: wow... everyone of those answers' code makes my eyes bleed.. then Im unable to cry because I feel so insignificant and small!

Answer (score 5):

Here is recursive extendable implementation. Tested for first order of pattern complexity.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

struct Match {
  Match():_next(0) {}
  virtual bool match(const char * pattern, const char * input) const {
    return !std::strcmp(pattern, input);
  }
  bool next(const char * pattern, const char * input) const {
    if (!_next) return false;
    return _next->match(pattern, input);
  }
  const Match * _next;
};

class MatchSet: public Match {
  typedef std::vector<Match *> Set;
  Set toTry;
public:
  virtual bool match(const char * pattern, const char * input) const {
    for (Set::const_iterator i = toTry.begin(); i !=toTry.end(); ++i) {
      if ((*i)->match(pattern, input)) return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
  void add(Match * m) {
    toTry.push_back(m);
    m->_next = this;
  }
  ~MatchSet() {
    for (Set::const_iterator i = toTry.begin(); i !=toTry.end(); ++i)
      if ((*i)->_next==this) (*i)->_next = 0;
  }
};

struct MatchQuestion: public Match  {
  virtual bool match(const char * pattern, const char * input) const {
    if (pattern[0] != '?')
      return false;
    if (next(pattern+1, input))
      return true;
    if (next(pattern+1, input+1))
      return true;
    return false;
  }
};

struct MatchEmpty: public Match {
  virtual bool match(const char * pattern, const char * input) const {
    if (pattern[0]==0 && input[0]==0)
      return true;
    return false;
  }
};

struct MatchAsterisk: public Match {
  virtual bool match(const char * pattern, const char * input) const {
    if (pattern[0] != '*')
      return false;
    if (pattern[1] == 0) {
      return true;
    }
    for (int i = 0; input[i] != 0; ++i) {
      if (next(pattern+1, input+i))
        return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
};

struct MatchSymbol: public Match {
  virtual bool match(const char * pattern, const char * input) const {
    // TODO: consider cycle here to prevent unnecessary recursion
    // Cycle should detect special characters and call next on them
    // Current implementation abstracts from that
    if (pattern[0] != input[0])
      return false;
    return next(pattern+1, input+1);
  }
};

class DefaultMatch: public MatchSet {
  MatchEmpty empty;
  MatchQuestion question;
  MatchAsterisk asterisk;
  MatchSymbol symbol;
public:
  DefaultMatch() {
    add(&empty);
    add(&question);
    add(&asterisk);
    add(&symbol);
  }
  void test(const char * p, const char * input) const {
    testOneWay(p, input);
    if (!std::strcmp(p, input)) return;
    testOneWay(input, p);
  }
  bool testOneWay(const char * p, const char * input) const {
    const char * eqStr = " == ";
    bool rv = match(p, input);
    if (!rv) eqStr = " != ";
    std::cout << p << eqStr << input << std::endl;
    return rv;
  }

};


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
  using namespace std;

  typedef vector<string> Strings;
  Strings patterns;

  patterns.push_back("*");
  patterns.push_back("*hw");
  patterns.push_back("h*w");
  patterns.push_back("hw*");

  patterns.push_back("?");
  patterns.push_back("?ab");
  patterns.push_back("a?b");
  patterns.push_back("ab?");

  patterns.push_back("c");
  patterns.push_back("cab");
  patterns.push_back("acb");
  patterns.push_back("abc");

  patterns.push_back("*this homework?");
  patterns.push_back("Is this homework?");
  patterns.push_back("This is homework!");
  patterns.push_back("How is this homework?");

  patterns.push_back("hw");
  patterns.push_back("homework");
  patterns.push_back("howork");

  DefaultMatch d;
  for (unsigned i = 0; i < patterns.size(); ++i)
    for (unsigned j =i; j < patterns.size(); ++j)
      d.test(patterns[i].c_str(), patterns[j].c_str());

    return 0;
}
```

If something is unclear, ask.

Comment: I appreciate any design comments.

Comment: The `*` matches the previous symbol zero-or-more times, and `?` matches the previous symbol one-or-more times.  In several places here, you have `?` and `*` with no preceding symbol.  Is this intentional?

Comment: * matches any amount of any symbols, ? matches zero or one symbol

Comment: Now that I think about it, bash matches ? as exactly one symbol, I should've probably do the same

Answer (score 2):

try to make a list of interesting test cases:

> is_match("dummy","dummy") should
>   return true;
>
> is_match("dumm?y","dummy") should
>   return true;
>
> is_match("dum?y","dummy")
>   should return false;
>
> is_match("dum*y","dummy") should
>   return true;

and so on ...

then see how to make the easier test pass, then the next one ...

Comment: You trying to teach them TDD at the same time? ;)  Why not post some simple instructions on how to use Google Test, while your at it: http://code.google.com/p/googletest/

Comment: Plz correct me if Im wrong but...shouldn't `s_match("dum?y","dummy")` return **true**. `m?` matches the letter **m** zero or more times right?

Comment: @giddy: Zero or one times, see e.g. [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html). `*` would mean *"zero or more times"*.

Comment: @gideon, no, `ab?` means that either `a` or `ab`. `ab?` will match `abbbb`, and `ab?` will match `ac`, but `ab?` will not match `aab` because there is no two `a` in the `ab?`.

Answer (score 2):

Cheat. Use `#include <boost/regex/regex.hpp>`.

Comment: would be a perfect answer for a real world project : 1) never trust your boss when he says "we will never have a use for all other regex stuff, just ? and *, promised" 2) don't reinvent warm water when you have hot water on the tap. My answer was based on the asumption this is homework ...

Comment: Also, the questio is tagged C as well as C++.

Answer (score 1):

Didn't test this, actually code it, or debug it, but this might get you a start...

```
for each character in the pattern
  if pattern character after the current one is *
    // enter * state
    while current character from target == current pattern char, and not at end
      get next character from target
    skip a char from the pattern
  else if pattern character after the current one is ?
    // enter ? state
    if current character from target == current pattern char
      get next char from target
    skip a char from the pattern
  else
    // enter character state
    if current character from target == current pattern character
      get next character from target
    else
      return false
return true
```

Comment: One important thing missing here is the ability to backtrack, otherwise the regex `ab?bc` couldn't match `abc`.

Comment: @Tim: I attempted to solve that by matching the `?` forward - "if the pattern character after the current one is ?"

Comment: But that doesn't work. The `b?` matches the `b`, then the next `b` can't match the `c` and the regex fails. There has to be a way to remember that the `b?` was optional, and to exercise that option. That's probably what Basilevs means by "add a stack here" - you need to remember all positions where there are several ways of applying the current regex token and try all possible combinations before declaring failure.

Comment: @Tim: I think there's some ambiguity to what I meant by "get next" vs "skip a char" vs "current".  Maybe I'll just rewrite the darn thing in C =P  I am fairly certain you don't need a stack, as long as you're willing to live with hacks that won't apply to more complicated features (that we currently aren't implementing) in the pattern.

Comment: @Tim: Oh, I get what you're saying now...  Maybe I should get off my butt and go read a book on compilers, like I've been wanting to :)

Answer (score 1):

The full power of regular expressions and finite state machines are not needed to solve this problem. As an alternative there is a relatively simple dynamic programming solution.

Let match(i, j) be 1 if it is possible to match the the sub-string *string*[i..n-1] with the sub-pattern *pattern*[j, m - 1], where n and m are the lengths of *string* and *pattern* respectively. Otherwise let match(i, j) be 0.

The base cases are:

- match(n, m) = 1, you can match an empty string with an empty pattern;
- match(i, m) = 0, you can't match a non-empty string with an empty pattern;

The transition is divided into 3 cases depending on whether the current sub-pattern starts with a character followed by a '*', or a character followed by a '?' or just starts with a character with no special symbol after it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int is_match(char* pattern, char* string)
{
  int n = strlen(string);
  int m = strlen(pattern);

  int i, j;
  int **match;

  match = (int **) malloc((n + 1) * sizeof(int *));
  for(i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
    match[i] = (int *) malloc((m + 1) * sizeof(int));
  }

  for(i = n; i >= 0; i--) {
    for(j = m; j >= 0; j--) {
      if(i == n && j == m) {
        match[i][j] = 1;
      }
      else if(i < n && j == m) {
        match[i][j] = 0;
      }
      else {
        match[i][j] = 0;
        if(pattern[j + 1] == '*') {
          if(match[i][j + 2]) match[i][j] = 1;
          if(i < n && pattern[j] == string[i] && match[i + 1][j]) match[i][j] = 1;
        }
        else if(pattern[j + 1] == '?') {
          if(match[i][j + 2]) match[i][j] = 1;
          if(i < n && pattern[j] == string[i] && match[i + 1][j + 2]) match[i][j] = 1;
        }
        else if(i < n && pattern[j] == string[i] && match[i + 1][j + 1]) {
          match[i][j] = 1;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  int result = match[0][0];

  for(i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
    free(match[i]);
  }

  free(match);

  return result;
}

int main(void)
{
  printf("is_match(dummy, dummy)  = %d\n", is_match("dummy","dummy"));
  printf("is_match(dumm?y, dummy) = %d\n", is_match("dumm?y","dummy"));
  printf("is_match(dum?y, dummy)  = %d\n", is_match("dum?y","dummy"));
  printf("is_match(dum*y, dummy)  = %d\n", is_match("dum*y","dummy")); 

  system("pause");

  return 0;
}
```

The time complexity of this approach is O(n * m). The memory complexity is also O(n * m) but with a simple modification can be reduced to O(m).

Answer (score 0):

Simple recursive implementation. It's slow but easy to understand:

```
int is_match(char *pattern, char *string)
{
    if (!pattern[0]) {
        return !string[0];
    } else if (pattern[1] == '?') {
        return (pattern[0] == string[0] && is_match(pattern+2, string+1))
            || is_match(pattern+2, string);
    } else if (pattern[1] == '*') {
        size_t i;
        for (i=0; string[i] == pattern[0]; i++)
            if (is_match(pattern+2, string+i)) return 1;
        return 0;
    } else {
        return pattern[0] == string[0] && is_match(pattern+1, string+1);
    }
}
```

Hope I got it all right.

Comment: i think the for loop should be for(i=0;string[i]==pattern[0];i++);(note the trailing ";"),did you make a typo?

Comment: actually the else if(pattern[1]=='*') branch could be replace by for( i = 0 ; string[i]==pattern[0];i++)
           ;//note this semi-colon
    return is_match(pattern+2,string+i);
so how do you think?

Comment: @Tracy: nope. Then "x*xxxxxy" will fail to match "xxxxxy". As I said my answer is slow but simple because handling these cases correctly is not simple unless you're willing to convert the pattern to a state machine.

Answer (score 0):

A C program to find the index,from where the sub-string in the main string is going to start.
    enter code here

```
#include<stdio.h>
int mystrstr (const char *,const char *);
int mystrcmp(char *,char *);
int main()
{
    char *s1,*s2;//enter the strings, s1 is main string and s2 is substring.
    printf("Index is %d\n",mystrstr(s1,s2));
    //print the index of the string if string is found
}
//search for the sub-string in the main string
int mystrstr (const char *ps1,const char *ps2) 
{
    int i=0,j=0,c=0,l,m;char *x,*y;
    x=ps1;
    y=ps2;
    while(*ps1++)i++;
    while(*ps2++)j++;
    ps1=x;
    ps2=y;
    char z[j];
    for(l=0;l<i-j;l++)
    {
        for(m=l;m<j+l;m++)
            //store the sub-string of similar size from main string
            z[c++]=ps1[m];
        z[c]='\0'
        c=0;
        if(mystrcmp(z,ps2)==0)
        break;
    }
    return l;
}


int mystrcmp(char *ps3,char *ps4) //compare two strings
{
    int i=0;char *x,*y;
    x=ps3;y=ps4;
    while((*ps3!=0)&&(*ps3++==*ps4++))i++;      
    ps3=x;ps4=y;
    if(ps3[i]==ps4[i])
        return 0;
    if(ps3[i]>ps4[i])
        return +1;
    else
        return -1;
}
```